# Ensure proper return when closing multiple modal views

Tags: wpf, mvvm, modal-dialog

I came across some code today that looked something like below.
It's very simplified and hopefully you can read through errors.

ViewHelper class that opens new views.

```
public void DisplayView(ViewBase viewModel)
{
    view = GetView(viewModel);
    view.Owner = GetOwner(view);
    view.ShowDialog(); //Will never return if view.Owner closes itself before view.
}
```

View model class with the ability to open another dialog.

```
public class MyViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private Action<int> _callback;
    public int SelectedInt { get; set; }

    public MyViewModel(Action<int> callback)
    {
        _callback = callback;
    }

    public void AcceptAndClose()
    {
        _callback.Invoke(SelectedInt);
        Close();
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        // Closes corresponding View
    }

    public void NewDialog()
    {
        var callback = p => 
        {
            this.SelectedInt = p;
            this.AcceptAndClose();
        }
        ViewHelper.DisplayView(new MyViewModel(callback));
    }
}
```

The problem I found with it is that if we open a new Dialog with NewDialog() in the MyViewModel class, and the new viewmodel runs AcceptAndClose(), it will never properly close because the its Owner closes itself through the callback before it gets to do it.

One can fix this by changing the AcceptAndClose() function so that it closes itself before Invoking the callback. But it seem very vulnerable to mistakes.
What are the best practices to avoid this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Believe me, when I say that this road is assured of failure in the future.
Your viewmodel should never has any knowledge of an view.

Your view should call the viewmodel.

It solves your issue also ;)

Comment: Agreed. I wrote an article about [MVVM Dialog Boxes here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/820324/Implementing-Dialog-Boxes-in-MVVM) which covers the issue of closing fairly comprehensively whilst still being easy to implement application-side. Essentially you need a behaviour that taps into the Closing event and calls your callback accordingly.